# Looping char* gives me Access violation writing location 0x00CFB310

Tags: c, char-pointer

i try to print simple c* string like this :

```
char *cc = "HEllo";

                for (char* inputPtr = cc; inputPtr[0]; inputPtr++) {
                    char c = inputPtr[0]++;
                    printf("%s",c);
                }
```

but im getting :
Access violation writing location 0x00CFB310.
on :

```
char c = inputPtr[0]++;
```

what is wrong here ?

Comment: @dandan78 This is not a good duplicate, because OP is not realizing he's incrementing the char, not the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are experimenting with `inputPtr[0]` as a substitution for `*inputPtr`. In many contexts, the two expressions produce the same result.

However, expression `inputPtr[0]++` is not the same as `*inputPtr++`, because `[0]` has [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `*`, but it has the same precedence as suffix `++`. Operators within this precedence level are applied left-to-right, so the first expression post-increments `inputPtr[0]`, a character inside a character literal. This is undefined behavior, hence you see a crash.

If you replace `inputPtr[0]++` with `*inputPtr++` and remove `inputPtr++` from loop header, your code is going to work fine:

```
for (char* inputPtr = cc; inputPtr[0]; ) {
    char c = *inputPtr++;
    printf("%c", c); // Replace %s with %c to print one character
}
```

Comment: The code with `inputPtr[0]++` changed to `*inputPtr++` will invoke *undefined behavior* for reading out-of-range. `inputPtr` is now incremented twice per loop and the terminating null-character will be skipped.

Comment: @MikeCAT You're right, he's doing a `for` loop, not a `while` loop, where it would make more sense. Thanks!

Comment: Im getting  Access violation reading location 0x00000048. on the printf

Comment: @user63898 That's because you used `%s` in place of `%c`. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

`inputPtr` is pointing at `"HEllo"`, which is a string literal.

Modifying string literal isn't allowed and trying to do so invokes *undefined behavior*.

`inputPtr[0]++` is trying to modify string literal. If data of string literal is located in read-only locations, it may lead to Segmentation Fault.

Comment: you could suggest fix `char cc[] = "HEllo";` then

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre why, when `inputPtr[0] + 1` would have the same effect here.

Comment: good point. I made some selective reading. Why on earth modifying some input data in-place? someone should suggest that to the OP instead of just pointing out the error (which makes that a duplicate question)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I don't think `inputPtr[0] + 1` will have the same effect because post-increment is used in the original code and `inputPtr[0]`, not `inputPtr[0] + 1` will be stored to `c` if `inputPtr[0]` were writable.

Answer (score 0):

String literals in C are *read only*, attempting to modify the characters in string literals leads to *undefined behavior*.

Any with `inputPtr[0]` you *do* modify the string since you increment the character `inputPtr[0]`.

This is the reason you should always use `const char *` when pointing to string literals.

If you want to modify the contents of the string you have to create an array:

```
char cc[] = "HEllo";
```

Comment: this char pointer in reallty im getting from API call , so how do i loop it ?
do i need to make copy of it to char[]?

Comment: @user63898 If you want to modify the contents of the string, then yes you should definitely create a copy.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have written, you can't modify a string literal. Change your declaration to `char cc[] = "HEllo";` and see what happens. The suggested declaration declares a string buffer that is modifiable.